# Is there an API for making a Google Chrome extension that reads the network resource request activity?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the Google Chrome developer window, there is a Network tab that shows you all the resources that a web page loads over time. Is there a way to access this data in a Google Chrome extension?

CLARIFICATION: I want to make a Chrome extension that needs to read this data and do something based on what it reads. So I should have asked, "is there a Chrome Extension API that allows this?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [experimental API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.webInspector.resources.html) for accessing network resources. Being experimental means that to use it users need to enable experimental API flag in their settings, plus you won't be able to submit such extension to the gallery.

Comment: This [API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.network.html) is no longer experimental.

Comment: Here is the [non-experimental API link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network)

Answer (score -5):

Right click on the web page, select "Inspect Element", select the network tab then refresh

Comment: The question is if we can achieve to read network tab contents but not to give directions for seeing network  request.